# Bokeh not handling colors properly with ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, bokeh

I am generating a Bokeh figure as follows:

```
from bokeh.plotting import ColumnDataSource,show,figure

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        x=test[:,0],
        y=test[:,1],
        label=[unquote_plus(vocab_idx[i]) for i in range(len(test))],
        color=colors))

TOOLS="box_zoom,pan,reset,box_select,wheel_zoom,help,hover"
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=600,tools=TOOLS)

renderer = p.circle(x='x',y='y',source=source,color='color')

show(p)
```

Where `test` is an array of XY coordinates, and `colors` is a list of RGB 3-tuples. The problem is, if I run the code above, I don't get any coloring (just white circles).

However, if generate the plot like this (note I'm using the exact same list of tuples to specify the colors):

```
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(test):
    p.circle(x=x,y=y, size=8, color=colors[i])
```

It works exactly as expected. I figure I must be doing something wrong in my first attempt, but can't figure out. I also tried this:

```
renderer = p.circle(x=test[:,0],y=test[:,1],color=colors,size=8)
```

But this also fails as in the first case (all white circles). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a known bug: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4096 as a workaround, convert the RGB tuples to hex color strings.

Comment: I can open a new question for this, but it's semi-related...the workaround you cite works fine, but how do i make a legend in this context (i.e. a label for each unique color in `source`)? I tried adding a `legend` column to my `ColumnDataSource` with the appropriate labels, and then adding `legend='legend'` to my call to `p.circle`, but that didn't work...

Comment: Legends created with glyph methods are created *per-glyph* so you would want to create a separate `circle` call for each group with a different `legend` value for each group.

Comment: FYI the OP should be fixed in `0.12` https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2622

Comment: Per @mcve, can you attach minimal `test` and `colors`?